# Are the different Superman comic series linked?

Tags: dc, superman, suggested-order, the-new-52, dc-rebirth

I've been trying to get back into comics, and am interested in collecting Superman single issues.

I am familiar with the "Triangle numbering" period of Superman, where the stories between Superman, Action Comics, Man of Steel, Adventures of Superman, etc. were linked and the triangle numbering helped determining the read order.

However I have picked up some issues of both Superman and Adventures of Superman after the Byrne "Man of Steel" mini series but before the triangle numbering kicked in.

**Are the stories linked between issues?**

If so is there an easy way to find out how should these be ordered?

I am also interested in the post-triangle numbering issues and have observed stories that continue between Action Comics and Superman (such as "Up, Up and Away" from 2006)

Is there also continuity between Superman and Action Comics from the New 52 and Rebirth era, or are there only certain stories that cross over?

Comment: This seems very broad.

Comment: @Valorum is it clear what I am asking?

Comment: Kinda. I'm not especially well equipped to answer it (I tend not to bother with single arcs since I own every single edition) but what you're asking covers potentially hundreds of comics across three distinct properties.

Comment: @Valorum I edited my Q to hopefully make it clearer. I don't so much need to know the order that every issue from the hundreds published should be read, but if there is generally a link between the stories in those series as there was during the triangle numbering period. Any resourses to find out further would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Superman and Batman comics are not as tightly connected as they were during the "triangle" phase in the 90s where they were effectively a single weekly title.  Each title has its own storyline running, sometimes coming close to contradicting each other if you choose to analyze them that closely. So you can "safely" read Action or Superman on their own, and not fear missing parts of the story.

Events will still cross between titles on occasion - the "New Super-Man" book is referenced in the Superman titles recently - but those mentioned are usually footnoted. Any major event crossing between the books are also mentioned explicitly, like the "Monster Man" event in the Bat-books recently